# TextView is always null in my Fragment when I try and setText it crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an app that has 1 main activity which calls 2 fragments. 1 fragment has a listview and if you click an item, it should open a new fragment containing information based on the index of the item clicked. When I try and change the text in the 2nd fragment call, my app crashes.

MainActivity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Communicator {

FragmentManager manager;
FragmentTransaction transaction;
FriendsFragment friendsFrag;
FeedFragment feedFrag;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    friendsFrag = new FriendsFragment();
    feedFrag = new FeedFragment();

    manager = getFragmentManager();
    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container, friendsFrag, "friendsFrag");
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void startFragment(int i) {

    manager = getFragmentManager();
    //FeedFragment frag = (FeedFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.feedFrag);

    transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, feedFrag);

    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
    feedFrag.updateFeedDisplay(i);
}
```

### }

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    >

</LinearLayout>
```

First fragment that is called:

```
public class FriendsFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

Communicator com;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)     {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendsfragment, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    com = (Communicator)activity;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    //com = (Communicator)getActivity();
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity(), R.array.test, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    com.startFragment(position);
   // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ITem: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}


}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Text"
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

2nd fragment:

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {

FeedFragmentData feed;
private static TextView fedTV;
//Communicator com;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 //   LayoutInflater lf = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    //return inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedfragment, container, false);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feedfragment, container, false);
    //fedTV = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.fedTV);
    feed = new FeedFragmentData(getActivity());
    //fedTV.setText(feed.getFeed(0));
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    //com = (Communicator)activity;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
//     feed = new FeedFragmentData(getActivity());
    fedTV = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fedTV);
}

public void updateFeedDisplay(int position) {

   // Toast.makeText(this, "HIii", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

   // fedTV = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fedTV);
    if (fedTV != null) {
        fedTV.setText("Haa");
    }


}
```

### }

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          >

<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="text"
        android:id="@+id/fedTV"/>
</ScrollView>
```

I produce this error when I remove the if (fedTV != null) and just setText. If I have the if statement then the textfield never changes
Logcat error:

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at albert.kim.fragments.FeedFragment.updateFeedDisplay(FeedFragment.java:53)
        at albert.kim.fragments.MyActivity.startFragment(MyActivity.java:41)
        at albert.kim.fragments.FriendsFragment.onItemClick(FriendsFragment.java:47)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:308)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1483)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3485)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4843)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: From where you are calling `updateFeedDisplay()` method. From other fragment then it may be reason for `NPE`.

Comment: @user370305 I thought that this was the error. But in my main activity where I call the method I call it after I transaction.commit(). I've tried putting it before, after. How can I make that method be called after the oncreateview?

Comment: @user370305 but isnt the proper convention to pass information from fragment -> activity -> fragment2? Thats the way I have it set up and its not working. My method is being called before the fragment is getting instantiated for some reason.

Comment: @user370305 I get data fine in onCreateView() in my 2nd fragment its just that the method updateFeedDisplay() is getting called before my onCreateView() is being called for some reason.

Comment: Why are some lines commented out yet they're essential?
Like when you're initializing:
`fedTV = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fedTV);`

Answer (score 0):

I instantiated the fedTV in my updateFeedDisplay() method and changed the declaration from private static to just private. It worked this time...